# React Native - Move to next input after maxlength

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm pretty much new to react native currently i'm building a small app to get a better idea on this i'm using react-native-paper as the ui library. Currently i'm stuck in an issue ie, i had two input fields with is maxlength as 3. I need to move to first input to next one automatically when first input acheived its maxlength ie, 3. I tried by adding `returnKeyType="next"` to the input field but its not working.

```
        <View style={styles.textinputViewleft}>
            <NumberInput 
            style={styles.textinput} 
            label="Digit"
            returnKeyType="next"
            value={digit.value}
            onChangeText={(text) => setDigit({ value: text, error: '' })}
            error={!!digit.error}
            errorText={digit.error}
            keyboardType="numeric"
            maxLength={3} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.textinputView}>
            <NumberInput 
            style={styles.textinput} 
            label="Count"
            value={count.value}
            onChangeText={(text) => setCount({ value: text, error: '' })}
            error={!!count.error}
            errorText={count.error}
            keyboardType="numeric"
            maxLength={3}  />
        </View>
```

[Snack link](http://snack.expo.io/@ssoorajs96/sjs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, create `ref` to get access to the inputs.

```
const ref = React.useRef();
```

Then pass it to the second `TextInput`.

```
<NumberInput 
  ref={ref}
  style={styles.textinput}
  ...
/>
```

When the length of your first input reaches 3, call `focus` to insert the cursor in the second Input.

```
onChangeText={(text) => {
  if (text.length === 3) {
    ref.current.focus();
  }
  setDigit({ value: text, error: '' });
}}
```

Comment: Wonderful answer, useRef is such a powerful hook.

Comment: @LeriGogsadze As i'm using react-native-paper library this method that you suggested above is not working. If we're importing the Textinput from the rect-native default library it will works. But in the specific ui library its not working.

Comment: @soorajspillai I tried and it works. Can you show me your `NumberInput` component?

Comment: I've changed the numberinput to textinput its also a custom component

http://snack.expo.io/@ssoorajs96/sjs

Comment: Yeah, that's why it didn't work. You have to use `forwardRef` hook. https://snack.expo.io/HgJK7hzIC check it out.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Working Example based on @Leri Gogsadze's existing answer :

```js
export default function App() {
  const [numOne, setNumOne] = useState('');
  const [numTwo, setNumTwo] = useState('');
  const ref = useRef();
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="enter number"
        maxLength={3}
        value={numOne}
        onChangeText={(value) => {
          setNumOne(value);
          if (value.length === 3) {
            ref.current.focus();
          }
        }}
        returnKeyType="next"
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        ref={ref}
        placeholder="enter name"
        maxLength={3}
        value={numTwo}
        onChangeText={(value) => setNumTwo(value)}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Working sample app: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/anxious-chocolates)

Comment: As i'm using react-native-paper library this method that you suggested above is not working. If we're importing the Textinput from the rect-native default library it will works. But in the specific ui library its not working.

Comment: If possible post an expo link of a dummy app having the issues you mentioned, will easy for us to reproduce the same scenarios and debug.

Comment: You can check this snack https://snack.expo.io/@ssoorajs96/sjs